# javascript: html5-pattern regex question

Tags: javascript, regex, html

When I run this script with `"\d+"` as pattern value, the regex doesn't work as I expected.
When I escape the backslash it works.
Is the backslash the only character that I have to escape?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter a number:</p>
<form id="form">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.getElementById( 'form' );
        var input = document.createElement( 'input' );
        input.name = 'amount';
        input.type = 'number';
        input.pattern = "\\d+";
        form.appendChild( input );
    </script>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash character in a string used as a RegEx expression just as you would in any JavaScript string.

> To include a literal backslash inside a string, you must escape the
>   backslash character. For example, to assign the file path c:\temp to a
>   string, use the following:
>
> `var home = "c:\\temp";`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Escaping_Characters

Comment: I don't think he wants to add a backslash but a number. the backlash should be escaped because it's in the string

Comment: Isn't that what I put? I don't really see the difference between my answer and your answer.

Comment: BTW - Let me know which bit of my answer you think is unclear and I'll happily change it.

Comment: your block quotes requires code format. the line with the file path.

Comment: OK, fixed. I've left the code in the quote blocks to make it clear that all that content is from MDN.

Comment: you should also probably note that it is escaped as a string not as a reg x pattern

Answer (score 2):

the back slash must be escaped as part of the strings syntax.

Comment: JavaScript recognises escape sequences in single quote delimited strings. Using single quotes won't help here.

Comment: seems like it,  I've confused with . fixed.